# PHP with Oracle XE - Login username not existing

Tags: php, authentication, oracle-xe

please help me with my thesis. I'm not a programmer so bear with me pls.

I have a fully working system that's in a PHP and MYSQL Database. But I need to change it to an Oracle XE so I downloaded it and set everything up. But now im having a problem making it work. Can you guys please help me?

So one of my problem is that the system doesnt recognize the username so I cannot login.

[image: Login Error]
Here is the code used. All in php.

Login.php

```
<div>
<form action="loginprocess.php" method="post" name="logForm" id="logForm" >
    <?php // Display error message
        if(!empty($_SESSION['error_msg']))  { echo "<p style=\"color:#FF0000; font-size: 14px; padding: 30px 5px 0 20px\" id=\"message\">".$_SESSION['error_msg']."</p>"; }
        unset($_SESSION['error_msg']);
    ?>

    <div class="6u 12u$" style="margin:0 auto">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="User Name / Last Name / e-mail" />
    </div>
    <br />

    <div class="6u 12u$" style="margin:0 auto">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>


    <div class="6u 12u$" style="margin:0 auto">
        <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember" value="1">Remember me
    </div>

    <div class="12u$">
        <ul class="actions">
            <li><input type="submit" value="Login" class="special" name="Login" id="Login"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br>

</form>
```

loginprocess.php

```
<?php
include 'settings/connect.php';
if(session_id() == '') { session_start(); } // START SESSIONS

    // Begin Login

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { $data[$key] = filter($value); }

// Begin log process
if(isset($_POST) && array_key_exists('Login',$_POST)){
    // Filter POST Variables

    $user_name = $data['username'];
    $pass = $data['password'];

    // Can use email, lastname or username to login
    // if (strpos($user_name,'@') === false) {
    //  $user_cond = "(username='$user_name' OR last_name='$user_name')"; 
    // }else{
    //  $user_cond = "email=$user_name"; 
    // }
$user_cond = "username = '$user_name'"; 
    $result = oci_parse($link, "SELECT user_ID,password,first_name,username,email,middle_name,last_name,user_level,approval FROM qmo.system_users WHERE $user_cond") or die (oci_error());
    // oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':user', $user_name);
    oci_execute($result); 
    $num = oci_num_rows($result);

    // Match row found with more than 1 results  - the user is authenticated. 
    if ( $num > 0 ) { 
        list($id,$pwd,$first_name,$username,$email,$middle_name,$last_name,$userlevel,$approved) = oci_fetch_row($result);  
        if(!$approved) {
            $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "Account not activated. Please check your email for activation code or contact the administrator";
            header("Location: index.php");
        }

        //check against salt
        if ($pwd === PwdHash($pass,substr($pwd,0,9))) { 
            if($_SESSION['error_msg'] == ""){ 
                // this sets session and logs user in
                session_regenerate_id (true); //prevent against session fixation attacks.

                $full_name = $first_name." ".$middle_name." ".$last_name;

               // this sets variables in the session
                $_SESSION['user_id']= $id;
                $_SESSION['full_name'] = $full_name;
                $_SESSION['user_level'] = $userlevel;
                $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

                //update the timestamp and key for cookie
                // $stamp = time();
                // $ckey = GenKey();
                // $update = oci_parse($link, "update qmo.system_users set ctime='$stamp', ckey = '$ckey' where user_ID='$id'") or die(oci_error());
                // oci_execute($update); 

                //set a cookie 
             //   if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
                //  setcookie("user_id", $_SESSION['user_id'], time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                //  setcookie("user_key", sha1($ckey), time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                //  setcookie("user_name",$_SESSION['user_name'], time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                // }


            //  if ($userlevel == '1') { // check the value of the 'status' in the db
//                   //go to admin area
//                   header("Location: index.php");
            //  } else {
            //       //go to members area
            //       header("Location: backend/index.php");



            // } 
                header("Location: backend/index.php");

            }
        }else{ $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "Invalid Login. Please try again with correct user name and password."; header("Location: index.php"); }
    }else{ $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "Error - Invalid login. No such user exists"; header("Location: index.php"); }
} // End log process?>
```

I'll also add my connection settings since the functions are here.
connect.php

```
    <?php 
CONNECT TO DB
define ("DB_HOST", "localhost/XE");     // HOST NAME
define ("DB_USER", "system");  // DATABASE USER
define ("DB_PASS","qwqwqw");    // DATABASE PASSWORD
define ("DB_NAME","qmo");   // DATABASE NAME
define ("DB_PREFIX",""); // DATABASE PREFIX

    $link = oci_connect(DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_HOST);
    $db_name = DB_NAME;

    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");

    define("COOKIE_TIME_OUT", 10); //specify cookie timeout in days (default is 10 days)
    define('SALT_LENGTH', 9); // salt for password

    /* Specify user levels */
    define ("ADMIN_LEVEL", 2);
    define ("STUDENT_LEVEL", 1);
    define ("GUEST_LEVEL", 0);

    // DEFINE INCLUDE DIRECTORY
    define("ROOT",$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
    define("PAGE",ROOT."/paging/");
    define("SETTING",ROOT."/settings/");

    /*************** reCAPTCHA KEYS****************/
    $publickey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // get your key at http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha
    $privatekey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // get your key at http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha

// BEGIN FUNCTIONS SECTION  


    //GET URL function
    function url(){
      return sprintf(
        "%s://%s%s",
        isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http',
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
      );
    }

    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

    // Base URL Function
    function baseurl($url) {
      $result = parse_url($url);
      return $result['scheme']."://".$result['host'];
    }

    $urllink = url();
    define('SERVER_PATH', dirname(url()));

    // get url address function
    function getAddress() {
        $protocol = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
        return $protocol.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }


    /**** PAGE PROTECT CODE  ********************************
    This code protects pages to only logged in users. If users have not logged in then it will redirect to login page.
    If you want to add a new page and want to login protect, COPY this from this to END marker.
    Remember this code must be placed on very top of any html or php page.
    ********************************************************/

    function page_protect() {
        session_start();
        global $link; 

        /* Secure against Session Hijacking by checking user agent */
        if (isset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
            if ($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
                logout();
                exit;
            }
        }

        // Need to check authentication key - ckey and ctime stored in database before allowing sessions
        /* If session not set, check for cookies set by Remember me */
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !isset($_SESSION['user_name']) ) {
            if(isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['user_key'])) {

                /* Double check cookie expiry time against stored in database */
                $cookie_user_id  = filter($_COOKIE['user_id']);
                $rs_ctime = mysqli_query($link, "select `ckey`,`ctime` from `".DB_PREFIX."system_users` WHERE `user_ID` ='$cookie_user_id'") or die(mysqli_error());
                list($ckey,$ctime) = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_ctime);
                // coookie expiry
                if( (time() - $ctime) > 60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT) {
                    logout();
                }
                /* Security check with untrusted cookies - dont trust value stored in cookie.       
                /* Also do authentication check of the `ckey` stored in cookie matches that stored in database during login*/

                if( !empty($ckey) && is_numeric($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isUserID($_COOKIE['user_name']) && $_COOKIE['user_key'] == sha1($ckey)  ) {
                    session_regenerate_id(); //against session fixation attacks.
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
                    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_COOKIE['user_name'];
                    /* query user level from database instead of storing in cookies */  
                    list($user_level) = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($link, "select userlevel from ".DB_PREFIX."system_users where user_ID='$_SESSION[user_id]'"));

                    $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
                    $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); 
                }else{
                    logout();
                }
            }else{
                header("Location: index.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
    // End page protect function


    // function oci_escape_string($string) {
    //   return str_replace(array('"', "'", '\\'), array('\\"', '\\\'', '\\\\'), $string);
    // }
    // Data filtering function
    function filter($data) {
        global $link;

        $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));

        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            // $data = oci_escape_string($data);
            return $data;

    }

    function EncodeURL($url) {
        $new = strtolower(ereg_replace(' ','_',$url));
        return($new);
    }

    function DecodeURL($url) {
        $new = ucwords(ereg_replace('_',' ',$url));
        return($new);
    }

    function ChopStr($str, $len){
        if (strlen($str) < $len)
            return $str;
            $str = substr($str,0,$len);
        if ($spc_pos = strrpos($str," "))
            $str = substr($str,0,$spc_pos);
            return $str . "...";
    }   

    // Email Validation function
    function isEmail($email){ return preg_match('/^\S+@[\w\d.-]{2,}\.[\w]{2,6}$/iU', $email) ? TRUE : FALSE; }

    // Username Validation Faunction
    function isUserID($username) {  if (preg_match('/^[a-z\d_]{5,20}$/i', $username)) { return true; } else { return false; }  }    

    // URL Validation Function
    function isURL($url) {
        if (preg_match('/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?/i', $url)) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    } 

    //add http to URL
    function addhttp($url) {
        if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
            $url = "http://" . $url;
        }
        return $url;
    }

    // Password Checker function
    function checkPwd($x,$y) {
        if(empty($x) || empty($y) ) { return false; }
        if (strlen($x) < 8 || strlen($y) < 8) { return false; }
        if (strcmp($x,$y) != 0) {
            return false;
        } 
        return true;
    }

    // Password Generator function
    function GenPwd($length = 7) {
        $password = "";
        $possible = "0123456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz"; //no vowels  
        $i = 0;    
        while ($i < $length) {     
            $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);     
            if (!strstr($password, $char)) { 
                $password .= $char;
                $i++;
            }
        }
        return $password;
    }

    // Key Generator or use Password Generator as alternative function
    function GenKey($length = 7)
    {
        $password = "";
        $possible = "0123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";   
        $i = 0;     
        while ($i < $length)
        { 
            $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
            if (!strstr($password, $char))
            { 
                $password .= $char;
                $i++;
            }
        }
        return $password;
    }

    // Logout Function
    function logout()
    {
        global $link;
        session_start();
        $rdirect = baseurl(url()).$_SESSION['oldURL'];
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || isset($_COOKIE['user_id']))
        {
            mysqli_query($link, "update `".DB_PREFIX."system_users` SET `ckey`= '', `ctime`= ''  WHERE `user_ID`='$_SESSION[user_id]' OR  `user_ID` = '$_COOKIE[user_id]'") or die(mysqli_error());
        }           

        /************ Delete the sessions****************/
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_name']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_level']);
        unset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();

        /* Delete the cookies*******************/
        setcookie("user_id", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
        setcookie("user_name", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
        setcookie("user_key", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");

        if(isset($rdirect)){ header('Location: index.php'); }
        else { header('Location: index.php'); }
    }

    // Password and salt generation (password encryption)
    function PwdHash($pwd, $salt = null)
    {
        if ($salt === null)
        {
            $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, SALT_LENGTH);
        }
        else
        {
            $salt = substr($salt, 0, SALT_LENGTH);
        }
        return $salt . sha1($pwd . $salt);
    }

    // Check User Levels
    function Admin()
    { // Administrator
        if($_SESSION['user_level'] == ADMIN_LEVEL) { return 1; }else{ return 0 ; }
    }

    function Student()
    { // student
        if($_SESSION['user_level'] == STUDENT_LEVEL) { return 1; }else{ return 0 ; }
    }

    function Guest()
    { // guest
        if($_SESSION['user_level'] == GUEST_LEVEL) { return 1; }else{ return 0 ; }
    }




// END FUNCTION SECTION 
?>
```

Please help me with this. I've be stuck on this for a week already. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get any errors? Add [error reporting](//php.net/manual/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s): `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and tell us what you get.

Comment: Literally, I'm not getting any error but logically, it doesnt function the way I want to be. Im sure my login credentials are correct but it says "User doesnt exist (as can be seen on the screenshot".

thank you for your response, it's my first time posting here so Im sorry if it's too long

Comment: Also, could you [narrow the code down to the problem segment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Most of the code, from what I can tell, is immaterial to your issue. (I'm not familiar with Oracle Database XE, though, and PHP isn't my primary language, so I can't help you *too* much on that front. I'm just trying to help tailor your question so it's easier for others who *can* help you to understand your issue and respond to it.)